# How to tidy/fix PyCXX's creation of new-style Python extension-class?

Tags: c++, initialization, python-c-api, new-style-class, pycxx

I've nearly finished rewriting a C++ Python wrapper (PyCXX).

The original allows old and new style extension classes, but also allows one to derive from the new-style classes:

```
import test

// ok
a = test.new_style_class();

// also ok
class Derived( test.new_style_class() ):
    def __init__( self ):
        test_funcmapper.new_style_class.__init__( self )

    def derived_func( self ):
        print( 'derived_func' )
        super().func_noargs()

    def func_noargs( self ):
        print( 'derived func_noargs' )

d = Derived()
```

The code is convoluted, and appears to contain errors ([Why does PyCXX handle new-style classes in the way it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564257/why-does-pycxx-handle-new-style-classes-in-the-way-it-does))

My question is: **What is the rationale/justification for PyCXX's convoluted mechanism? Is there a cleaner alternative?**

I will attempt to detail below where I am at with this enquiry.  First I will try and describe what PyCXX is doing at the moment, then I will describe what I think could maybe be improved.

---

When the Python runtime encounters `d = Derived()`, it does `PyObject_Call( ob ) where ob is the`PyTypeObject`for`NewStyleClass`. I will write`ob`as`NewStyleClass_PyTypeObject`.

That PyTypeObject has been constructed in C++ and registered using `PyType_Ready`

`PyObject_Call` will invoke `type_call(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)`, returning an initialised Derived instance i.e.

```
PyObject* derived_instance = type_call(NewStyleClass_PyTypeObject, NULL, NULL)
```

Something like this.

(All of this coming from (http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/16/python-object-creation-sequence by the way, thanks Eli!)

type_call does essentially:

```
type->tp_new(type, args, kwds);
type->tp_init(obj, args, kwds);
```

And our C++ wrapper has inserted functions into the `tp_new` and `tp_init` slots of `NewStyleClass_PyTypeObject` something like this:

```
typeobject.set_tp_new( extension_object_new );
typeobject.set_tp_init( extension_object_init );

:
    static PyObject* extension_object_new( PyTypeObject* subtype, 
                                              PyObject* args, PyObject* kwds )
    {
        PyObject* pyob = subtype->tp_alloc(subtype,0);

        Bridge* o = reinterpret_cast<Bridge *>( pyob );

        o->m_pycxx_object = nullptr;

        return pyob;
    }

    static int extension_object_init( PyObject* _self, 
                                            PyObject* args, PyObject* kwds )
    {
        Bridge* self{ reinterpret_cast<Bridge*>(_self) };

        // NOTE: observe this is where we invoke the constructor, 
        //       but indirectly (i.e. through final)
        self->m_pycxx_object = new FinalClass{ self, args, kwds };

        return 0;
    }
```

Note that we need to bind together the Python Derived instance, and it's corresponding C++ class instance. (Why? Explained below, see 'X').  To do that we are using:

```
struct Bridge
{
    PyObject_HEAD // <-- a PyObject
    ExtObjBase* m_pycxx_object;
}
```

Now this bridge raises a question. I'm very suspicious of this design.

Note how memory was allocated for this new PyObject:

```
        PyObject* pyob = subtype->tp_alloc(subtype,0);
```

And then we typecast this pointer to `Bridge`, and use the 4 or 8 (`sizeof(void*)`) bytes immediately following the `PyObject` to point to the corresponding C++ class instance (this gets hooked up in `extension_object_init` as can be seen above).

Now for this to work we require:

a) `subtype->tp_alloc(subtype,0)` must be allocating an extra `sizeof(void*)` bytes
 b) The `PyObject` doesn't require any memory beyond `sizeof(PyObject_HEAD)`, because if it did then this would be conflicting with the above pointer

One major question I have at this point is:
Can we guarantee that the `PyObject` that the Python runtime has created for our `derived_instance` does not overlap into Bridge's `ExtObjBase* m_pycxx_object` field?

I will attempt to answer it: it is US determining how much memory gets allocated. When we create `NewStyleClass_PyTypeObject` we feed in how much memory we want this `PyTypeObject` to allocate for a new instance of this type:

```
template< TEMPLATE_TYPENAME FinalClass >
class ExtObjBase : public FuncMapper<FinalClass> , public ExtObjBase_noTemplate
{
protected:
    static TypeObject& typeobject()
    {
        static TypeObject* t{ nullptr };
        if( ! t )
            t = new TypeObject{ sizeof(FinalClass), typeid(FinalClass).name() };
                   /*           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is the bug BTW!
                        The C++ Derived class instance never gets deposited
                        In the memory allocated by the Python runtime
                        (controlled by this parameter)

                        This value should be sizeof(Bridge) -- as pointed out
                        in the answer to the question linked above

        return *t;
    }
:
}

class TypeObject
{
private:
    PyTypeObject* table;

    // these tables fit into the main table via pointers
    PySequenceMethods*       sequence_table;
    PyMappingMethods*        mapping_table;
    PyNumberMethods*         number_table;
    PyBufferProcs*           buffer_table;

public:
    PyTypeObject* type_object() const
    {
        return table;
    }

    // NOTE: if you define one sequence method you must define all of them except the assigns

    TypeObject( size_t size_bytes, const char* default_name )
        : table{ new PyTypeObject{} }  // {} sets to 0
        , sequence_table{}
        , mapping_table{}
        , number_table{}
        , buffer_table{}
    {
        PyObject* table_as_object = reinterpret_cast<PyObject* >( table );

        *table_as_object = PyObject{ _PyObject_EXTRA_INIT  1, NULL }; 
        // ^ py_object_initializer -- NULL because type must be init'd by user

        table_as_object->ob_type = _Type_Type();

        // QQQ table->ob_size = 0;
        table->tp_name              = const_cast<char *>( default_name );
        table->tp_basicsize         = size_bytes;
        table->tp_itemsize          = 0; // sizeof(void*); // so as to store extra pointer

        table->tp_dealloc           = ...
```

You can see it going in as `table->tp_basicsize`

But now it seems clear to me that PyObject-s generated from `NewStyleClass_PyTypeObject` will never require additional allocated memory.

Which means that this whole `Bridge` mechanism is unnecessary.

And PyCXX's original technique for using PyObject as a base class of `NewStyleClassCXXClass`, and initialising this base so that the Python runtime's PyObject for `d = Derived()` is in fact this base, this technique is looking good. Because it allows seamless typecasting.

Whenever Python runtime calls a slot from `NewStyleClass_PyTypeObject`, it will be passing a pointer to d's PyObject as the first parameter, and we can just typecast back to `NewStyleClassCXXClass`. <-- 'X' (referenced above)

So really my question is: why don't we just do this? ***Is there something special about deriving from `NewStyleClass` that forces extra allocation for the PyObject***?

I realise I don't understand the creation sequence in the case of a derived class. Eli's post didn't cover that.

I suspect this may be connected with the fact that

```
    static PyObject* extension_object_new( PyTypeObject* subtype, ...
```

^ this variable name is 'subtype'
I don't understand this, and I wonder if this may hold the key.

EDIT: I thought of one possible explanation for why PyCXX is using sizeof(FinalClass) for initialisation. It might be a relic from an idea that got tried and discarded. i.e. If Python's tp_new call allocates enough space for the FinalClass (which has the PyObject as base), maybe a new FinalClass can be generated on that exact location using 'placement new', or some cunning reinterpret_cast business. My guess is this might have been tried, found to pose some problem, worked around, and the relic got left behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCXX is not convoluted. It does have two bugs, but they can be easily fixed without requiring significant changes to the code.

When creating a C++ wrapper for the Python API, one encounters a problem. The C++ object model and the Python new-style object model are very different. One fundamental difference is that C++ has a single constructor that both creates and initializes the object. While Python has two stages; `tp_new` creates the object and performs minimal intialization (or just returns an existing object) and `tp_init` performs the rest of the initialization.

[PEP 253](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0253/), which you should probably read in its entirety, says:

> The difference in responsibilities between the tp_new() slot and the tp_init() slot lies in the invariants they ensure.  The tp_new() slot should ensure only the most essential invariants, without which the C code that implements the objects would break.  The tp_init() slot should be used for overridable user-specific initializations.  Take for example the  dictionary type.  The implementation has an internal pointer to a hash table which should never be NULL.  This invariant is taken care of by the tp_new() slot for dictionaries.  The dictionary tp_init() slot, on the other hand, could be used to give the dictionary an initial set of keys and values based on the arguments passed in.

...

> You may wonder why the tp_new() slot shouldn't call the tp_init() slot itself.  The reason is that in certain circumstances (like support for persistent objects), it is important to be able to create an object of a particular type without initializing it any further than necessary.  This may conveniently be done by calling the tp_new() slot without calling tp_init().  It is also possible  hat tp_init() is not called, or called more than once -- its operation should be robust even in these anomalous cases.

The entire point of a C++ wrapper is to enable you to write nice C++ code. Say for example that you want your object to have a data member that can only be initialized during its construction. If you create the object during `tp_new`, then you cannot reinitialize that data member during `tp_init`. This will probably force you to hold that data member via some kind of a smart pointer and create it during `tp_new`. This makes the code ugly.

The approach PyCXX takes is to separate object construction into two:

- `tp_new` creates a dummy object with just a pointer to the C++ object which is created `tp_init`. This pointer is initially null.
- `tp_init` allocates and constructs the actual C++ object, then updates the pointer in the dummy object created in `tp_new` to point to it. If `tp_init` is called more than once it raises a Python exception.

I personally think that the overhead of this approach for my own applications is too high, but it's a legitimate approach. I have my own C++ wrapper around the Python C/API that does all the initialization in `tp_new`, which is also flawed. There doesn't appear to be a good solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small C example that shows how Python allocates memory for object of classes derived from C types:

```
typedef struct
{
    PyObject_HEAD
    int dummy[100];
} xxx_obj;
```

It also needs a type object:

```
static PyTypeObject xxx_type = 
{
    PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
};
```

And a module initialization function that initializes this type:

```
extern "C"
void init_xxx(void)
{
    PyObject* m;

    xxx_type.tp_name = "_xxx.xxx";
    xxx_type.tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE;

    xxx_type.tp_new = tp_new; // IMPORTANT
    xxx_type.tp_basicsize = sizeof(xxx_obj); // IMPORTANT

    if (PyType_Ready(&xxx_type) < 0)
        return;

    m = Py_InitModule3("_xxx", NULL, "");

    Py_INCREF(&xxx_type);
    PyModule_AddObject(m, "xxx", (PyObject *)&xxx_type);
}
```

What is missing is the implementation of `tp_new`: The Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_new) require that:

> The `tp_new` function should call `subtype->tp_alloc(subtype, nitems)` to allocate space for the object

So lets do that and add a few printouts.

```
static
PyObject *tp_new(PyTypeObject *subtype, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    printf("xxx.tp_new():\n\n");

    printf("\t subtype=%s\n", subtype->tp_name);
    printf("\t subtype->tp_base=%s\n", subtype->tp_base->tp_name);
    printf("\t subtype->tp_base->tp_base=%s\n", subtype->tp_base->tp_base->tp_name);

    printf("\n");

    printf("\t subtype->tp_basicsize=%ld\n", subtype->tp_basicsize);
    printf("\t subtype->tp_base->tp_basicsize=%ld\n", subtype->tp_base->tp_basicsize);
    printf("\t subtype->tp_base->tp_base->tp_basicsize=%ld\n", subtype->tp_base->tp_base->tp_basicsize);

    return subtype->tp_alloc(subtype, 0); // IMPORTANT: memory allocation is done here!
}
```

Now run a very simple Python program to test it. This program creates a new class derived from `xxx`, and then creates an object of type `derived`.

```python
import _xxx

class derived(_xxx.xxx):
    def __init__(self):
        super(derived, self).__init__()

d = derived()
```

To create an object of type derived, Python will call its `tp_new`, which in turn will call its base class' (`xxx`) `tp_new`. This call generates the following output (exact numbers depends on the machine architecture):

```
xxx.tp_new():

    subtype=derived
    subtype->tp_base=_xxx.xxx
    subtype->tp_base->tp_base=object

    subtype->tp_basicsize=432
    subtype->tp_base->tp_basicsize=416
    subtype->tp_base->tp_base->tp_basicsize=16
```

The `subtype` argument to `tp_new` is the type of the object being created (`derived`), it derives from our C type (`_xxx.xxx`), which in turns derives from `object`. The base `object` is of size 16, which is just `PyObject_HEAD`, the `xxx` type has an additional 400 bytes for its `dummy` member for a total of 416 bytes and the `derived` Python class adds additional 16 bytes.

Because `subtype->tp_basicsize` accounts for the sizes of all three levels of the hierarchy (`object`, `xxx` and `derived`) for a total of 432 bytes, the right amount of memory is being allocated.

Comment: Aha! So this means the way 'd' is laid out in memory is: [PyObject_HEAD(16bytes)][_xxx.xxx(400 bytes)][derived(16 bytes)]. Now I can finally see why the presence of a derived class requires something like PyCXX's Bridge. I can see why they had to move away from the original typecasting solution they had for old-style classes.

Comment: Seeing as you've figured out the question I *should* have been asking in the first place, would you care to relocate this answer if I re-ask the question properly? ([HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666958/how-does-python-allocate-memory-for-objects-of-classes-derived-from-c-types) -- I think this is a valuable resource, and nobody will find it from such an obscure question. A comment on the first answer could redirect.

Comment: What happens with multiple inheritance? Will Python resolve duplicate base classes into the same memory space instead of duplicating it?

Comment: In Python you cannot derive from two completely different C types. You can derive from `defaultdict` and `dict`, because `defaultdict` derives from `dict`- in terms of memory layout it is just as having `defaultdcit` alone - but you cannot derive from both `dict` and list` because there is no way to reconcile their memory layout.